# Can't get Sql Statement to work in a Case Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert the Date and Day Of The Week into a table. The Table should contain 30 days excluding Sunday. I can not get the Insert inside the case statement to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Declare @StartDate as Date = DateAdd(day,-30,GetDate())
Declare @DOW varchar(10)
Declare @adddaycnt int 
Declare @RecsWrite int
Set @RecsWrite = 0
Set @adddaycnt = 0
While @RecsWrite <= 30
Begin
Select @DOW = DateName(dw,DateAdd(dw,@adddaycnt,@startDate)) 
Select Case When @DOW <> 'Sunday' then 
Insert Into temp_ProdSaleInv (ProdDate,DOW) 
Values(
Convert(varchar(10),DateAdd(day, @adddaycnt,@startDate),101), 
DateName(dw,DateAdd(dw, @adddaycnt,@startDate) 
)
)
End 

Select Case When @DOW <> 'Sunday' then 
Set @RecsWrite = @RecsWrite + 1
Set @adddaycnt = @adddaycnt + 1
Else 
Set @adddaycnt = @adddaycnt + 1
End
```

Comment: replace your case with IF statement.

Answer (score 0):

The case statements won't work like you coded. Try this with `IF` instead.

```
Declare @StartDate as Date = DateAdd(day,-30,GetDate())
Declare @DOW varchar(10)
Declare @adddaycnt int 
Declare @RecsWrite int
Set @RecsWrite = 0
Set @adddaycnt = 0
While @RecsWrite <= 30
Begin
Select @DOW = DateName(dw,DateAdd(dw,@adddaycnt,@startDate)) 
IF @DOW <> 'Sunday' 
BEGIN
Insert Into temp_ProdSaleInv (ProdDate,DOW) 
Values(
Convert(varchar(10),DateAdd(day, @adddaycnt,@startDate),101), 
DateName(dw,DateAdd(dw, @adddaycnt,@startDate) 
)
)

END


IF @DOW <> 'Sunday'
BEGIN
   Set @RecsWrite = @RecsWrite + 1
   Set @adddaycnt = @adddaycnt + 1
END
Else 
BEGIN
   Set @adddaycnt = @adddaycnt + 1
END

End
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CASE` statement [evaluates a list of conditions and returns one of multiple possible result expressions.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql)

Instead, you are trying to actually run CRUD statements in the `CASE` statements.

Therefore, use something like [IF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql) conditions instead.